# qt window menu bar

Tags: qt

in any window (gui ) there appears a menubar and minimize, maximize and close icons. How is it possible to hide this bar.

Brgds,

kNish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Window flags](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qt.html#WindowType-enum) to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a window frameless by calling:

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

See the [window flags](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qt.html#WindowType-enum) documentation to see how else you can change the appearance of windows.